# Getting links to a category in Joomla

Tags: joomla, hyperlink, external, categories

Even just 30 minutes google the forums and found nothing ... I am interested in - actually I see a new link to a category created not by me, while also having access to the database (to see it directly) being available to only access the admin panel. Help me please.

Comment: please be more specific, what you have asking about?? Do you have more then 1 users??

Comment: No, I'm the only one admin user. I just need to know how to get a link to a category from the admin panel

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a link to determined category, you have to understand that there is a component responsible of show the content, if you see this [Link](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/1.5/Introduction#Creating_the_Entry_Point), you can pass parameters in the url, therefore a link to  category will be something like this:

`index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=4&Itemid=6`

where category it's the type of view. You can put category or section
Put blog in the layout parameter if you want to show the articles as blog form, this parameter its optional
id its the number of the category id
and finally itemid its the id of the menu from was clicked